# How to add 1 fixed element in a list Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you please tell me if it is possible to create a `ListView` but always have 1 fixed item at the end of the list, thus allowing a new card to be added. As shown in the screenshot below. There is a regular list of cards and at the end a card with an `Add New Point` button, when clicked, an action occurs (adding a new element to the end of the list).
If you know how to implement such an element as Add New Poynt, please tell me, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase `itemLength` by 1 and while check if the index is last one, provide your fixed widget.

```dart
 ListView.builder(
  itemCount: itemLength + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == itemLength) {
      return Text("last Item");
    }
    return Text("item $index");
  },
),
```

Comment: As I understand it, instead of this line return Text("last Item"); - I add an element which will be the last one. And instead of this return Text("item $index"); - add other elements?

Comment: yes, `last item` is your add tile which will be last widget and else builder will get item widget

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help :)
Another question is, are there any materials on Flutter that can be studied to improve the level of language proficiency?

Comment: I will recommend [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/)  and [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)

Answer (score 4):

Very simple, use `[...oldList]` to create a new List and add your fixed item after it like `[...oldList, fixedItem]`.

**Example**:
[image]
**Example with ListView**:
[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help :) As I understand it, there are many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is **only logic** please try it your own widget. Because I have not laptop.

**This code has syntax error please chaeck it because i have not laptop **

```
int howManyWidgetDraw = 5;

  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: howManyWidgetDraw,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int 
    index){

      if(howManyWidgetDraw==index.length){
        return InkWell(
           onTap(){
  howManyWidgetDraw=howManyWidgetDraw+1;
   //Call setstate method.  
},
    child: Text("last element print")); 

}
 else{

     return Text("first four element");

     } 

}

  ),

);
```

Have any issue please ask me?

Comment: I didn’t understand a little, maybe this line child: Text("last element print")); do you mean it needs to be added to the InkWell widget? And then you indicated it in a slightly different place.

Comment: But this line howManyWidgetDraw=howManyWidgetDraw+1 means that it will add one more element to the list? But at the same time, the last element will remain

Comment: Yes please try it. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Works, just tweaked a little. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ListView.separated:

```
ListView.separated(
      itemCount: _myList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
             return /* Your list item widget here */;
      }, 
      separatorBuilder: (context, index){ 
            if(index == _myList.length-1) {return Text('Add New Poynt');}
            else {return SizedBox();}
      }
),
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help :) As I understand it, there are many solutions.