# add a fixed element in a FirestoreListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use `firebase_ui_firestore` package. I want to set a banner( fixed element) to 1st item of below list. There is not index option. Therefore, I don't have idea about it.

Below is my code

```
FirestoreListView<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                pageSize: 4,
                query: usersQuery,
                itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> user = snapshot.data();
                  return FeedBox(
                    imageUrl: user['imageUrl'],
                    displayName: user['displayName'],
                  );
                },
              )
```

Comment: Are you searching for these: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71879814/18265570) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49567995/18265570)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found it.

```
FirestoreQueryBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                query: usersQuery,
                builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
                  // ...
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.docs.length +1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      // if we reached the end of the currently obtained items, we try to
                      // obtain more items
                      if (snapshot.hasMore &&
                          index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
                        // Tell FirestoreQueryBuilder to try to obtain more items.
                        // It is safe to call this function from within the build method.
                        snapshot.fetchMore();
                      }
                      if (index == 0) {
                        return Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          height: 100,
                        );
                      } else {
                        final user = snapshot.docs[index -1].data();
                        return FeedBox(
                          imageUrl: user['imageUrl'],
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              )
```